# How to submit Plink "Access granted. Press Return to begin session" prompt automatically

Tags: windows, batch-file, ssh, putty, plink

I'm writing a simple Windows batch script to allow me to execute some Linux command on my remote server with the help of `plink.exe`.

```
call set argument1=plink -pw mypwsswd username@172.19.48.111 cd ~/project; make clean; make -j8
call plink %%argument1%%
```

In a word, it will rebuild my C++ project on the remote server.

When I double click the batch, it works except that I have to type an <kbd>Enter</kbd> each time.

> Access granted. Press Return to begin session

[image]

As you see, after I getting this windows, I have to type an <kbd>Enter</kbd> to continue.

Is there some way to avoid this? For example, typing an enter automatically?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Since PuTTY 0.71 you get that prompt for security purposes, when you login in an interactive mode. See [PuTTY vulnerability vuln-auth-prompt-spoofing](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/vuln-auth-prompt-spoofing.html).

To use a batch mode, use [`-batch` switch](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink-option-batch). That way you not only get rid of that prompt. It will also make sure the command does not hang on various other prompts that may occur, when something changes. Instead the command fails straight away.

If you want to keep the interactive mode, but avoid this specific prompt only, use [`-no-antispoof` switch](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink-option-antispoof).