# How to ignore/suppress errors while trying to execute command from PuTTY through cmd

Tags: batch-file, ssh, cmd, putty

I want to lock my arch laptop using .bat file on my Windows machine.

I wrote this in my batch:

```
start C:\some_path\putty.exe -load "naptop@nick" -m C:\some_path\remote.cmd
```

And remote.cmd contains:

```
xfce4-session-logout --suspend;exit 0;
```

It works perfect! But when I don't have an internet connection, I have an error:

[image: screen]

Can I somehow ignore any errors when script can't execute my command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use PuTTY for automating command execution.

Use [Plink](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html) (part of PuTTY package). It takes the same arguments as PuTTY. Additionally you will want to add [`-batch` switch](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink-option-batch) to [skip any prompts that you may get](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57735695/850848).

```
C:\some_path\plink.exe -batch -load "naptop@nick" -m C:\some_path\remote.cmd
```

With Plink you can even specify your command directly on its commandline:

```
C:\some_path\plink.exe -batch -load "naptop@nick" xfce4-session-logout --suspend;exit 0;
```

Comment: Thanks you! It worked. 
Now I can lock both my devices simply pressing additional button on my mouse :)